# Need help with calculating asymptote equation

Tags: functions, asymptotics, graphing-functions, generating-functions

I need to calculate the equation in form of $$ f(x)= \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{px^2+bx+c} $$
The asymptote has these properties:

- Vertical asymptotes on x = 2 and  x = 1
- Horizontal asymptote on y = 0
- It went through (-2,0) and (0,-1)

I've tried doing the vertical using $$ px^2+qx+r = p (x-2) (x-1) 
= p (x^2-3x+2) $$
and the horizontal using $$ \frac{a}{p}=0 $$ meaning that the value of a = 0
I've also tried to calculate where it intersects x with $$ ax^2+bx+c=a(x+2) $$
What I'm confused with are the steps after that.

Comment: Are you sure that $(0,-1)$ is on this curve? It looks like $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Does the asymptote or the function go through $(2,0)$ and $(0,-1)?$  If you plug $x=0$ into your form you get $f(0)=1$  $(2,0)$ being on the curve is also inconsistent with the data as it gives $2b+c=0$ while your factorization of the denominator gives $\frac 23b+c=0$

Comment: Oh wait it's supposed to pass through $$ (-2,0) $$ instead